# I need to setup session replication on liferay servers

Tags: liferay-7, session-replication

Session replication between Liferay Community Edition server.

I have installed liferay community edition on my servers,i also setup database to it and configured TCP clustering between two servers,clustering is working perfectly on both the servers. I also tried to configure session replication between the servers, but it is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please tell me what you exactly want.